# Nest Js (Node Js Framework) - How to start server on Digital Ocean using pm2?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, nestjs, nodejs-server

I have developed my project in the Nest JS framework. My main file in the src folder (src/main.ts). How can I start the server on my Digital Ocean server?

Answer (score 9):

After you build the project, then it will have `main.js` file under `/dist`.
So just run:

```sh
pm2 start PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT/dist/main.js --name=YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Comment: I have done like this, and its started but when i run project on my browser its not working...

Comment: i dont know why it's not working but first please check if your app is running correctly